# Hide a group of columns based on maximum cell value in column

Tags: google-sheets, show-hide

I fear I need a script for this purpose unless there is a way to do this without scripts. There is a failed attempt at script in the script editor of the document linked below which can be erased.

I would like to hide irrelevant groups of columns (see darker borders for each size group) depending on the maximum value in column H.

If a batch with a value in column H (number of package sizes) is larger than 1 then we would like to unhide the groups of columns relevant to the number of packages sizes.

1. If there are 2 package sizes unhide L-M
2. If there are 3 package sizes unhide L-Q
3. If there are 4 package sizes unhide L-T
4. If there are 5 package sizes unhide L-W
5. If there are 6 package sizes unhide L-Z
6. Otherwise, we would like to have the extra groups of columns (L-Z) hidden.

It is OK to unhide the columns for all the rows even if there is just one batch which is larger than 1.

[image]

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nvwkVQXQc7eT9UQ4U7HJoaANbVheFfa77_LgfbvQ68s/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time learning a little script and here is what I ended up with. Note that the column groups are slightly shifted in my script example.

```
function onEdit(e) {

    // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
    var range = e.range;
    range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());

    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var clmnwdth = activeSheet.getRange("A4:A12").getValues();
    var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math, clmnwdth);

    Logger.log(maxi); 

    if (maxi == 0) {
        activeSheet.setColumnWidths(5, 20, 10)
    } else if (maxi == 1) {
        activeSheet.setColumnWidths(5, 20, 10)
    } else if (maxi == 2) {
        activeSheet.setColumnWidths(9, 16, 10), activeSheet.setColumnWidths(1, 8, 100)
    } else if (maxi == 3) {
        activeSheet.setColumnWidths(13, 12, 10), activeSheet.setColumnWidths(1, 12, 100)
    } else if (maxi == 4) {
        activeSheet.setColumnWidths(17, 8, 10), activeSheet.setColumnWidths(1, 16, 100)
    } else if (maxi == 5) {
        activeSheet.setColumnWidths(21, 4, 10), activeSheet.setColumnWidths(1, 20, 100)
    } else {
        activeSheet.setColumnWidths(1, 24, 100)
    }
}
```